# gulp-eslint stopping runSequence unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, gulp, eslint

I have a js linting task:

**js-lint.js**

```
import eslint from 'gulp-eslint';
import gulp from 'gulp';
import util from 'gulp-util';

import config from '../config';


gulp.task('js-lint', (callback) => {
  gulp
    .src(config.js.lint)
    .pipe(eslint({ envs: ['browser'] }))
    .pipe(eslint.format())
    .on('end', callback);
});
```

This and other tasks are used in my main gulpfile like so:

**gulpfile.babel.js**

```
gulp.task('build', (callback) => {
  runSequence(
    'clean',
    'js-lint',
    'scss-lint',
    [
      'fonts',
      'images:production',
      'js:production',
      'scss:production',
      'svg-sprite:production',
    ],
    callback,
  );
});
```

The `build` task runs `clean` and `js-lint` (which passes) but then stops the `runSequence`. If I comment out the usage of `js-lint` the build completes as expected.

I am not using `eslint.failAfterError()` and the linting is working correctly as expected. So why does the process stop?

Comment: You should have a return statement in your  'js-lint' task so gulp knows that task has completed.  So return gulp.src(config.js.lint).....  Hopefully all your other tasks have return statements as well.

Comment: @Mark I've discovered this is indeed the problem here. However my js-lint task setup is an example of how all my tasks are setup. I thought using the callback did the job required for syncing correctly with runSequence.

Comment: It may work if you do call your callback - so callback() with the parentheses added when you call it.

Comment: I feel like there was a reason I switched form normal returns to using the callback method I currently use. Can't remember what it was now so will run some tests when I get a chance to find out.